# TFS2010 build for VS2005 Projects

Tags: msbuild

We have migrated few projects from TFS2008 to TFS2010 by using the method-

1.Attch TFS2008 DB to TFS2010 DB

2.Tfsconfig import

3.Delete the project not required.

There are few projects in the migrated projects which use VS2005. They do not want to do any change in their project and want to use VS2005 to work with migrated projects. We have applied couple of patches in VS2005 and now they are able to access the TFS2010 projects from VS2005.

However we are clueless about the build configuration. We have configured build server for their Collection...now what configuration needs to be changed in TFsbuild.proj to make the build run again.

Is there any more steps required to make the build work?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks Upfront.

Kabir

Answer (score 0):

If you have not had a build definition for you TFSbuild.proj then you will need to create one. In your build definition, you will need to choose UpgradeTemplate.xaml as the build process template. In TFS 2010 this template is used to run legacy build definitions.

See how to run build with the UpgradeTemplate.xaml [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647553.aspx).

I also found this useful [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/c1f636c8-0d11-4e2b-825a-0b5d6d05c73c) in the MSDN Build Automation forum that tells you the differences between 2010 and 2005 build processes.